# Conected to TV and control device via remote

Tags: samsung, hdmi, smart-tv, samsung-dex

I connected my Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 with my LG tv over HDMI and it works good so far.
But what I am missing, is the possibility to control my tablet with the LG remote controller.
When I connect my tablet via SmartView it works, but not when doing so via HDMI.
(I want the connection to be via HDMI because of different reasons.)

Is there some option that I missed?
Or is it simply not possible to send the needed signals over HDMI to my tablet?

If so, do you know of some workaround? Like connecting your smartphone to the tablet and use it as touchpad? I would like to avoid buying a bluetooth mini keyboard.

Kind regards

Comment: For forwarding remote control commands via HDMI the tablet would have to support "HDMI CEC". As the tablet is not directly connected via HDMI but instead a MHL adapter is used I don't know if the HDMI CEC commands can pass this adapter at all and second if the tablet supports HDMI CEC commands at all.